# What is a proper function to check if input is empty/blank?

Tags: php

I've been using the `empty` function to validate if a form submission is made blank. However, I just realized that `empty` passes `"   *whitespace*   "` as NOT empty, which is obviously not what I want.

Examples:

```
    $text = "is this empty?";
    if (empty($text)) {
        echo 'Yes, Empty!';
     } 
             // return is NOT empty

    $text = "         ";
    if (empty($text)) {
        echo 'Yes, Empty!';
     } 
             // return is NOT empty
```

Right now I am using:

```
    $text = "         ";
    if (!trim($text)) {
        echo 'Yes, Empty!';
     } 
             // return is Yes, Empty!
```

I need to understand:

1. What is `empty` used for?
2. Am I properly using `trim` for my purposes?
3. Is their another function I can use specifically for my purpose?

Comment: [Here's an excellent and thorough explanation](http://kunststube.net/isset/) by one of SO's frequent PHP contributors

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use both `trim()` and `empty()` together:

```
$text = "         ";
if (empty(trim($text))) {
    echo 'Yes, Empty!';
}
```

Comment: PHP docs say not to do that. What benefit does it serve? If any? http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php

Comment: It's just a simple two step process. Remove and leading and trailing whitespace, in this case all of it, and then check if it's empty. It's perfectly fine to do.

Comment: That's going to issue a parse error prior to PHP 5.5 _PHP Fatal error:  Can't use function return value in write context_

Comment: DOCS say to just use `trim($name) == false`

Comment: Yeah, You should trim() before empty()

Comment: only feed defined variables into `empty($var)` and not nested functions eg `empty(trim($var))`

Answer (score 1):

1. Empty is used for checking if something is, well, empty. If there are spaces, it is not empty.
2. Trim removes the spaces before the first, and after the last character of your string. If there are no characters the trim will make your string with blank spaces empty. So yes, you are using it correct here.
3. As the previous answer said, you can use both empty and trim together if you don't want spaces to prevent your string from being empty. But the prefered way is to check if trim($string) is false.